# A < HPL < Complement(A) What can you say about A and Complement(A)?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

Suppose we have the language

$ \overline L = \{x∈\{0,1\}*:x∉L\}$

And we know that

$A ≤ HPL ≤ \overline A$

where HPL is the Halting problem.

We need to state whether A is finite, countably infinite and whether $A$ and $ \overline A$ is recursive or not or re or not.

We know that A reduces to HPL and HPL is re and therefore **A is re**. Since HPL reduces to $\overline A$ and HPL is not recursive then **$\overline A$ is not recursive**. Furthermore, if we know that a language is not recursive but its complement is re then the language is not re. We know so far that $\overline A$ is not recurisve but $A$ is re then it means that **$\overline A$ is not re**. Furthermore if you know that a language L is not re then *either* $\overline L$ is not re *or* $\overline L$ is re but not recursive. We know that $\overline A$ is not re but A is re and therefore, we can say that **A is not recursive.**

Can anybody tell me if my deduction is any good? Also, how can I know if A is finite/ count infinite? Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis appears to be correct. But some clarity may help you.
Let's analyse each case and check whether it is consistent with given information.
As $\text{HPL} \leq \overline{A}$, $\overline{A}$ cannot be finite or recursive.

\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{If A is }  & \textbf{Then }\overline{A} \textbf{ is}\\
\hline
\mbox{Finite} & \mbox{Contradiction - }\overline{A} \text{ has to be FA; Violates HPL} \leq \overline{A} \\
\hline
\mbox{Recursive} & \mbox{Contradiction - }\overline{A} \text{ has to be recursive; Violates HPL} \leq \overline{A}\\
\hline
\mbox{Recursively Enumerable} & \text{Non-Recursively Enumerable}\\
\mbox{but not Recursive} & \\
\hline
\mbox{Non-Recursively Enumerable} & \mbox{Contradiction - Violates } A \leq \text{HPL}\\
\hline
\end{array}

You can now infer countability based on this information.